# Divide-by-N binary clock sequence algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary, computer-science, clock

I'm not quite sure how to describe what I mean, so let me try to explain by example (bear with me).

When you simply increment an integer you get a binary sequence like so (let's assume 8 bits for this question):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
[ ... etc ... ]
```

One way to visualize this is that each column represents a "clock". Each clock/column is half the frequency of its right neighbor.

So the right-most clock has one `0` followed by one `1`, etc.  The next clock has two `0`s followed by two `1`s, etc and so on...

I'm interested in a sequence of binary strings in which each clock is an integer division of its neighbor.

So the right-most clock is still one `0`, one `1`, the next clock is still two `0`s, two `1`s, but the third clock is *three* `0`s and *three* `1`s, etc.

Instead of `/1 /2 /4 /8 /16 ...` it's now `/1 /2 /3 /4 /5 ...`.

The sequence now looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
[ ... etc ... ]
```

**Question**: Is there an operation/algorithm which can give me the value at `i` given the value at `i-1`?

In other words, let's say I'm at the 4th step (`0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1`). Is there some operation I can perform on this number to get the value at the 5th step (`0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0`), and similarly for any other step?

In the divide-by-2 case you simply increment the number (`i++`) but in the divide-by-N case I can't seem to figure out a similar way to go from one to the next. Am I missing something obvious?

I've tried translating the sequencing into decimal but that pattern is `0, 1, 2, 7, 12, 29, 58, etc` which doesn't stand out to me as anything obvious.

The brute-force way that I'm doing it now is that I have an array of counters (one for each column/clock) and I independently reset each count when the respective column's "period" is reached (so 2 for the first column, 3 for the next, etc). But that feels ugly.

I'd love to do this directly on the number without requiring an array of counters.  Is this even possible? Is this a known sequence? I'm not even sure what to Google to be honest. I'd appreciate any kind of leads on this. I'm happy to go down the rabbit hole with some guidance.

**UPDATE**

As per @borrible's observation, there are more than one values for `i-1` for a given `i` so it turns out the solution to my original question is ambiguous.  So I will expand my question to allow `i` as an input (in addition to the `i-1`th value.

Comment: Don't know if that helps, but the sequence is listed here: http://oeis.org/A175879 .

Comment: You can trivially compute every bit in such a number from its index, is that enough? Maybe you can compute an index back from a number too and increment that way..

Comment: I have this weird feeling that you indeed cannot find number i given i-1, but you can fairly trivially find the number at index n by summing all potentials of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8 ...) using modulo 1,2,3,4... on each binary digit.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing `i` you are only going be able to generate the successor to a given sequence if that sequence uniquely implies `i` (modulo the number of bit sequences).  If this is not the case the successor to a given sequence is ambiguous.

Lets consider the first few sequences for 3 bits:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
```

Note that `0 1 0` is succeeded by both `1 1 1` and `0 1 1`; i.e. it is ambiguous.  Given `0 1 0` but not `i` you cannot deduce the next sequence.  You can see a similar ambiguity in 4 bit sequences for `0 1 1 1` etc...

In other words, without knowing `i`, your problem is not generally solvable.

Comment: ah that's a good call. I've updated my question to allow for `i` as an input value.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence can be considered as a set of state machines, each with `2,4,6,...,16` states. The least common multiple of `2,4,6,...,16`, i.e. the length of the sequence, is 1680. Eight bits only lets us represent 256 values, so even if we were allowed to select the state encoding (which we aren't!), we wouldn't be able to uniquely identify all possible states.

If we know the index `i` (or, as the sequence length is 1680, it is sufficient to know the index modulo 1680), digit `j` is given by `(i mod (2 * j)) / j`.